# Given $E:V\rightarrow V$ s.t. $E^2=E$, prove $V=V_0 \ \oplus V_1$ and $E$ is diagonalizable

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

> Let $V$ be a vector space over $F$ and $E:V\rightarrow V$ a linear transformation such that $E^2=E$
>
> Prove:
>
> $\text{(a)}$ if $\lambda \in F$ is an eigenvalue of $E$, then $\lambda =0$ or $\lambda =1$
>
> $\text{(b)}$ $V=V_0 \ \oplus V_1$ and $E$ is diagonalizable.

I proved $\text{(a)}$, but sturggling with $\text{(b)}$.

My try:

Taking some $v\in V_0 \cap V_1:$ $v\in V_0 \Rightarrow Ev=0$, $v\in V_1 \Rightarrow Ev=v$.

So we get: $0=Ev=v$.

As for the sum, I tried to represent $v$ as $v=Ev +(v-Ev), \forall  \ v \in V$, but got stuck.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: You are on the right track.You should try and show that the image and the kernel of $E$ are disjoint. The sum you have written reflects that, since $Ev $ is in the image, and $E(v- Ev) = Ev- E^2v = 0$, so $v-Ev$ is the kernel. Now, the question is, can you show that the kernel and image are disjoint? In any case, $V_0 $ is the kernel and $V_1$ is the image (or the other way). You should also look up infinite dimensional results for idempotent operators, once you have all the background knowledge.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг They can’t be disjoint, but can have a trivial intersection.

Comment: @amd Thank you for pointing that out. Yes, they have a trivial intersection, this is because if $w = Ev$ and $Ew = 0$, then $E(Ev) = 0 \implies w = Ev = 0$.

Comment: You're saying I should look at $V_0$ and $V_1$ as the kernel and image of $E$, and prove they have trivial intersection. I have no problem proving that, but how do I reason such a transition looking at them as the kernel and the image?

Comment: Hint: What’s the minimal polynomial of $E$?

Comment: @amd Haven't studied that yet, and as these are homework, I cannot use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Quick proof:* Since $E^2-E=0$, the minimal polynomial of $E$ is $\lambda^2-\lambda=\lambda(\lambda-1)$, a product of unique linear factors, therefore $E$ is diagonalizable and $V$ is the direct sum of its eigenspaces, i.e., $V=V_0\oplus V_1$.

*Direct proof:* You’ve already shown that $V_1$ and $V_2$ have a trivial intersection. By definition, $V_0=\ker E$. Per астон’s hint, for any $v\in V$, $E(v-Ev)=Ev-E^2v=Ev-Ev=0$, hence $v-Ev\in\ker V=V_0$. Furthermore, $E(Ev)=Ev$ for all $v\in V$, so $Ev\in V_1$. Therefore, $v=(v-Ev)+Ev$ is the sum of an element of $V_0$ and an element of $V_1$. Since $V$ is the direct sum of the eigenspaces of $E$, there is a basis of $V$ that consists of eigenvectors of $E$, hence $E$ is diagonalizable.

Comment: Could you please explain why is $Ev \in V_1$?

Comment: $E(Ev)=E^2v=Ev=1(Ev)$, so $Ev$ is an eigenvector of $E$ with eigenvalue $1$.

Comment: Oh I see it now. And how do I conclude that $E$ is diagonalizable?

Comment: $V$ is the direct sum of $E$’s eigenspaces, so has a basis consisting of eigenvectors of $E$.

Comment: Just to slightly expound on @amd's point: you can pick bases for each of the individual eigenspaces. You can take their union are create a new basis for a larger space. Since $V$ is the direct sum of the eigenspaces, the union will contain exactly $n$ linearly independent vectors, since $V_0$ and $V_1$ had no element in common, their bases can't contain two similar elements. Now it's clear that $E$ has a diagonal representation; the basis of the eigenspaces of $E$, which give the basis for $V$, can be used to represent $E$ as a diagonal matrix.