# Prove that $V=V_0\oplus V_1$ where $T(v_0)=0$ for all $v_0\in V_0$ and $T(v_1)=v_1$ for all $v_1\in V_1$, where $T$ is an idempotent linear trans.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, idempotents

Let $T:V\rightarrow V$ be an idempotent linear transformation. Prove that $V=V_0\oplus V_1$ where $T(v_0)=0$ for all $v_0\in V_0$ and $T(v_1)=v_1$ for all $v_1\in V_1$.

EDIT:
My attempt:

Since $T(v_0)=0$ for all $v_0\in V_0$, we have that $V_0=\ker T$.  Since $T(v_1)=v_1$ for all $v_1\in V_1$, we have that $V_1=ImT$.
If $T=0$, then the problem is trivial, so suppose $T\neq 0$.
Let $v\in V$.  As $T=T^2\implies Tv=T^2v\implies T(v-Tv)=0$.  So, $v-Tv=\theta\in \ker T$.  Thus $v=\theta+Tv$.  Now, as $T(Tv)=Tv$ for all $v\in V$, we have that $Tv=v$ whenever $v\in V_1$.
Thus, $v=\theta+Tv$ is the sum of two elements, where $\theta\in V_0$ and $Tv\in V_1$.  So, $V=V_0+V_1$.
Let $v\in V_0\cap V_1$.  Then, $v\in V_0$ implies that $Tv=0$ and $v\in V_1$ implies $Tv=v$.  Thus $0=Tv=v$ and so $v=0$, thus $V_0\cap V_1=\{0\}$; hence $V=V_0\oplus V_1$.

Comment: See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2223421/given-ev-rightarrow-v-s-t-e2-e-prove-v-v-0-oplus-v-1-and-e-is-dia?rq=1)

Comment: @ArcticChar Thank you!  Would you mind looking at my attempted answer posted below?

Comment: You should write "where $V_0, V_1$ are defined by $V_{0}=\{v\in V\mid Tv=0\}$ and $V_{1}=\{v\in V\mid Tv=v\}$."

Comment: the simplest proof I could think of is under the 'post-script', here:  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4021347/if-pp-pp-and-p2-p-then-show-that-p-p/4021435#4021435  no prior knowledge of eigenvalues is needed

Comment: @user8675309 Can you check if my attempt below would work?  :)

Comment: From your 1st paragraph.... 2 things jump out.  (i) In general for a finite dim linear operator (idempotent or not) if $\text{rank}\big(T^2\big)=\text{rank}\big(T\big)$ then $V = \text{im }T \oplus \ker T$-- equivalently being rank stable means the eigenvalue 0 is semi-simple.  You may want to prove this to yourself as it will be useful here and elsewhere. (ii) You've written $V_1 =\text{im }T$ but I only see proven that $V_1\subseteq \text{im }T$, though this feels like a nitpick.

Comment: @user8675309 So, if I let $w\in ImT$, then could I say $w=T(v)$ for some $v\in V$, ... now I'm stuck.  But, do we even need this?  Couldn't we just use that $V_1\subseteq Im T$ and still have the result?